# Random freezing on my pc

Tags: freeze

Ever since building my PC, it has been freezing randomly. Everything stops, the last frame is stuck on display, sound goes on for a little while, before a horrendous noise starts playing (a little different every time). So far I've installed a new graphics card, swapped out the hard drive for a SSD, got a new power supply, wiped my system multiple times, tried different operating systems and borrowed a friends ram stick to test it. So far everything has been swapped except for the motherboard and CPU.

Hardware

1. AMD RX 570 4GB
2. HyperX 8 GB ram 2666 MHz
3. ASRock ab350m motherboard
4. 450W Corsair PSU
5. Samsung 860 EVO SSD
6. AMD Ryzen 3 2200G

I'm starting to think something is simply wrong with my configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, for starters, you have the minimum system PSU limitation for the graphics card you have. That's giving you zero headroom for anything else. Based on the behavior, it also sounds like a bad PCIe slot. Moving the GPU to a different PCIe slot can test this, but your board only has 1 PCIe x16 slot.

Comment: You could also remove the GPU and see if you still have problems. This would narrow it down to a bad PCIe slot or under powered PSU. Personally, I think you should get a larger PSU anyways. So I would get that first and then see what happens.